# check if Eval() is zero and condition display of anchor tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a repeater. and it fill certain numeric values within anchor tag. but if the value is zero i just want to display a span and anchor is discarded.

this is my code.

in HTML

```
    <td>
        <%if (ProcessMyDataItem(Eval("7DAYS").ToString()))
         {%>
<a class='aDetails' href="DashCheckInCheckOutDetails.aspx?building=<%=hiddenBuildingDetailsId.Value.ToString() %>&action=<%#Eval("ID") %>&day=7&name=<%#Eval("DESC") %>"><%#Eval("7DAYS") %> </a>
     <% }
      else
      {
          Response.Write("<span>0</span>");
      }
      %>
     </td>
```

and in the codebehind i have

```
public bool ProcessMyDataItem(string myValue)
        {
            if (myValue == "0")
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

but when i run it, shows an error

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control.

is there any way to check eval value is zero and if zero, display span, else display anchor tag.

Comment: as far as i know u CANT USE EVAL WITH C# Code inside Repeater! :(
Please check the solution for this issue in my posted answer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
 <%#Eval("7DAYS").ToString() != "0" ?"<a class='aDetails' href='DashCheckInCheckOutDetails.aspx?...'>3 </a>":" <span>0</span>"%>
```

This will work! i have tested!

**NOTE:** please add the `url` for the link as per your need.

**Updated Answer:**

```
  <%#Eval("7DAYS").ToString() != "0" ? "<a class='aDetails' href=DashCheckInCheckOutDetails.aspx?building="+hiddenBuildingDetailsId.Value+"&action="+Eval("ID") +"&day=7&name="+Eval("DESC") +">"+Eval("7DAYS")+" </a>" : " <span>0</span>" %>
```

This will work.

Comment: can u please format my anchor tag. i write it like this `<%#Eval("7DAYS").ToString() != "0" ? "<a class='aDetails' href='DashCheckInCheckOutDetails.aspx?building=<%=hiddenBuildingDetailsId.Value.ToString() %>&action=<%#Eval("ID") %>&day=7&name=<%#Eval("DESC") %>'><% Eval("7DAYS") %> </a>":"0"%>` but an error `Newline in constant`

Comment: if the hidden fields are in repeater it self then send the values from ItemDataBound event of repeater by finding the anchor tag

Comment: ok @Sharon i have formatted your anchor tag and it works for me..plz check the "updated answer" ! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think

```
<%# Eval("7DAYS") == 0 ? "empty" : "notempty" %>
```

Also if the field value type is supposed to be string you could do something along the lines of..

```
<%# (Eval("7DAYS") as string) ?? "empty" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change your 'a tag' like this,

```
<a class="aDetails" href="DashCheckInCheckOutDetails.aspx?building="+<%hiddenBuildingDetailsId.Value.ToString() %>&action=<%Eval("ID") %>&day=7&name=<%Eval("DESC") %>'><% Eval("7DAYS") %> </a>
```

Let me know the result.

Comment: Check it again. I have changed ""(quotes) instead of ''(Single). I was wrong at the first.

Comment: it shows error. is there enough double quotes in the link ?

Comment: Check with my answer again. It may show you the output.

Comment: hey @gkrishy you have not checked the condition in your answer! how it will display the <span> if the evaluation has "0" as mentioned by OP?